# QML постоянное обновление элемента

Tags: qt, qml

Есть данные, которые обновляются с постоянной скоростью, кроме того есть элемент `Image`, который показывается, или исчезает в зависимости от полученных данных.

В моем случае `Image` получает данные 1 раз и все. При работающей программе меняю данные Image не реагирует.

Как сделать так, чтобы данные воспринимались элементом `Image`  в реальном времени?

```
Image {
    id: indicator1
    x: 320
    y: 257
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    source: "../images/grn.png"
    visible:  stringList[0] === "0" || stringList[0] === "1" ? true : false
}
```

В `*.cpp`

```
void SerialPort::processSingleRecord (QByteArray value) {
     QString value2 = QString(value).trimmed();
     QStringList sl = value2.split(",");
     QString qqq;
     std::vector<QString> fullData;
     fullData.reserve(sl.size()+22);
     for(int i = 0; i < sl.size()-1; i++)
         fullData.push_back(sl[i]);
     QString lastItem = sl[sl.size()-1];
     for(int i = 0; i < lastItem.size(); i++)
         fullData.push_back(QString(lastItem[i]));
     for(int i = 0; i <fullData.size(); i++)
         qqq+= fullData[i]+',';
     set_serial_data(qqq);
}
```

В `*.qml`

```
 SerialPort
 {
     id: cppClass
 }
 property variant stringList: cppClass.serial_data.split(',')
 Image {
     id: indicator1
     x: 320
     y: 257
     fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
     source: "../images/grn.png"
     visible:  stringList[0] === "0" || stringList[0] === "1" ? true : false
 }
```

Comment: Тернарный оператор на visible избыточен, а по-сути вам необходимо менять видимость изображения там где вы получаете соответствующие данные, используя id компонента изображения indicator1

Comment: данные я получаю в .cpp файле, а в qml уже обращаюсь к нужному элементу....

Comment: Покажите код передачи данных из cpp в qml

Comment: В *.cpp
void SerialPort::processSingleRecord (QByteArray value){
QString value2=QString(value).trimmed();
QStringList sl=value2.split(",");
QString qqq;
std::vector<QString> fullData;
fullData.reserve(sl.size()+22);
for(int i = 0; i < sl.size()-1; i++)
fullData.push_back(sl[i]);
QString lastItem = sl[sl.size()-1];
for(int i = 0; i < lastItem.size(); i++)
fullData.push_back(QString(lastItem[i]));
for(int i = 0; i <fullData.size(); i++)
qqq+= fullData[i]+',';
set_serial_data(qqq);
}
В *.qml
SerialPort {id: cppClass}
property variant stringList: cppClass.serial_data.split(',')

Comment: Лучше добавьте код в вопрос, а то ничего не понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, у вас имеется класс `SerialPort`, в методе которого `processSingleRecord` вы обрабатываете пришедшие данные из какого-то последовательного порта.

В результате обработки у вас формируется строковый список первый элемент которого может быть либо `0`, либо `1`.

```
// SerialPort.cpp
class SerialPort {
public:
signals:
   void stateChanged(QString value); // Сигнализируем только о первом значении списка, что делать с остальными вы решите сами
private slots:
   void processSingleRecord(QByteArray data)
   {
       //...
       emit stateChanged( fullData[0] );
   }
}
```

Регистрируем класс `SerialPort` в `main.cpp`, например:

```
//...
qmlRegisterType<SerialPort>("ru.user321152", 1, 0, "SerialPort");
// ...
```

Переходим к `main.qml`.

```
import ru.user321152.SerialPort 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    Image {
        id: indicator1;
    }
    SerialPort {
        onStateChanged: { // обратите внимание на префикс on
            // value - строковое значение состояния
            indicator1.visible = value === "1"
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: так, с одним значением у меня все заработало ...
 onStateChanged: { 
            indicator1.visible = stringList[6] === "0"
}
а как мне теперь сделать так, чтоб работало вот так 
 onStateChanged: {  
            indicator1.visible = stringList[6] === "0"
            indicator1.visible = stringList[7] === "1"
            indicator1.visible = stringList[8] === "0"
            indicator1.visible = stringList[9] === "1"
}

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Лампочка зависит от нескольких состояний?

Comment: У меня 10 лампочек....

Comment: Сформулируйте вашу проблему и задайте новый вопрос. Я или кто-то другой постараемся ответить, а то так мне не очень удобно, ведь надо еще код писать

Comment: А нет, мой вариант Работает с вашим кодом... все отлично. Опробовал пока 3 лампы, каждая горит в зависимости от сигнала который поступает.